# how to multiply a numpy column array of size N to row array of size N in python to get N X N matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to multiply as like `[1,2] * [1,2].T = [[1,2],[2,4]]` using python. Is there any module function available in numpy or any other packages ?

I tried with numpy.matmul, numpy.dot and numpy.multiplication. Those aren't give much help

Comment: `np.outer` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication should be the other way round:

```
>>> np.array([[1,2]]).T @ np.array([[1,2]])
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are vectors, you need to exapnd the dimensions:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2])
>>> arr[:, None] @ arr.T[None, :]   # Or, arr[None, :].T @ arr[None, :]
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
>>> np.expand_dims(arr, axis=1) @ np.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

This is needed because `arr` is of shape `(2,)` that is a `1D` array.

To obtain the result you want you would need to multiply an array of shape `(2,1)` with `(1,2)` such that the resultant is `(2, 2)`:

```
>>> np.expand_dims(a, axis=1) # That is adding a dimension in columns
>>> np.expand_dims(a, axis=1).shape
(2, 1)
```

Your version doesn't work because `transpose` of a `1-D` array is same as the array itself.

```
>>> arr
array([1, 2])
>>> arr.T
array([1, 2])
```

If instead you had a `2D` array from the start, then transpose would have worked:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 2]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2]])
>>> arr.T
array([[1],
       [2]])
```